# EMR ssh on Master node

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, emr, amazon-emr

When i do ssh to master node as:

```
ssh hadoop@masternode -i key.pem
```

The connection is terminated with message :

```
Connection reset by peer
```

Is there anyway to maintain the ssh session for long time?

Comment: Check http://superuser.com/a/146641/249281

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add this to /etc/ssh/ssh_config:

```
ServerAliveInterval 60
```